# How to sum up property value of node type different from starting and ending node with Cypher in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have Neo4j community 3.5.5, where I built a graph data model with rail station and line sections between stations. Stations and line sections are nodes and connect is the relationship linking them.

[image: Stations and line sections]

I would like to name a starting station and an ending station and sum up length of all rail section in between. I tried the Cypher query below but Neo4j does not recognize `line_section` as a node type.

```
match (n1:Station)-[:Connect]-(n2:Station)
where n1.Name='Station1' and n2.Name='Station3'
return sum(Line_Section.length)
```

I know it is possible to do the summing with Neo4j Traversal API. Is it possible to do this in Cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the line section nodes have the label `Line_Section`, you can use a [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) pattern to get the entire path, [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension) to get a list of the line section nodes, [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/) to get the individual nodes, and then use [aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) to `SUM` all the line section lengths:

```
MATCH p = (n1:Station)-[:Connect*]-(n2:Station)
WHERE n1.Name='Station1' AND n2.Name='Station3'
UNWIND [n IN NODES(p) WHERE 'Line_Section' in LABELS(n)] AS ls
RETURN p, SUM(ls.length) AS distance
```

Or, you could use `REDUCE` in place of `UNWIND` and `SUM`:

```
MATCH p = (n1:Station)-[:Connect*]-(n2:Station)
WHERE n1.Name='Station1' AND n2.Name='Station3'
RETURN p, REDUCE(s = 0, ls IN [n IN NODES(p) WHERE 'Line_Section' in LABELS(n)] |
  s + ls.length) AS distance
```

[UPDATED]

```
Note: a variable-length relationship with an unbounded number of hops is expensive, and can take a long time or run out of memory.

If you only want the distance for the shortest path, then this should be faster:

MATCH
  (n1:Station { name: 'Station1' }),
  (n2:Station {name: 'Station3' }),
  p = shortestPath((n1)-[*]-(n2))
WHERE ALL(r IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) WHERE TYPE(r) = 'Connect')
RETURN p, REDUCE(s = 0, ls IN [n IN NODES(p) WHERE 'Line_Section' in LABELS(n)] |
  s + ls.length) AS distance
```

Comment: Match p = (n1:Station)-[:Connect*]-(n2:Station) takes forever. MATCH (n1:Station { name: 'Station1' }),(n2:Station {name: 'Station3' }), p = shortestPath((n1)-[*]-(n2))
WHERE all (r IN relationships(p) WHERE type(r)= 'Connect') works better.

Answer (score 2):

**First [`capture`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#named-paths) the path from a start node to the end node in a variable, then [`reduce`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce) the length property over it.**

```
MATCH path=(n1: Station { name: 'Station1' })-[:Connect]->(n2: Station { name: 'Station2' })
RETURN REDUCE (totalLength = 0, node in nodes(path) | totalLength + node.length) as totalDistance
```